# Blob Store responds with 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, blobstore, postman

I have an API running on Google App Engine that receives images via mail, trough App Engines incoming mail feature.

This means that I can not use Blob Store with JSP, as Google describes [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Uploading_a_blob) as a typical use-case. Instead I upload the image to Blob Store using [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit).

This works, as **the image gets uploaded to Blob Store, but Blob Store responds with `415 Unsupported Media Type`**. I've also tried to upload other file types and by using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), but Blob Store keeps responding with `415 Unsupported Media Type` even for successful requests.

## Retrofit

#### MailReceiver

```
String uploadUrl = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService()
                  .createUploadUrl("/api/camera/blobstore-response");
uploadUrl = uploadUrl.split("appspot.com/")[1]; // Remove the base URL.


TypedOutput body = new TypedOutput() {
  @Override
  public String fileName() {
    return fileName;
  }

  @Override
  public String mimeType() {
    return "image/jpeg";
  }

  @Override
  public long length() {
    return -1;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeTo(OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
  }
};

blobStoreApiService.uploadImage(uploadUrl, body);
```

#### BlobStoreApiService

```
  @Multipart
  @POST("/{path}")
  Object uploadImage(@Path(value = "path", encode = false) String uploadPath, @Part("file") TypedOutput image);
```

## Postman

Works, but receives `415 Unsupported Media Type`
[image: Working but receives <code>415 Unsupported Media Type</code>]

Identical to the request above, but added `Content-Type` header. This does not work (`400 Bad Request`)
[image: Identical to the request above, but added <code>Content-Type</code> header]

Comment: I'm seeing "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" even for the second request where you say that you set the Content-Type header. What's up with that?

Comment: That is the response header from Blob Store. EDIT: You were on the right track though, Nick! It looks like that's the response Blob Store got from the callback handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the Blob Store to get an URL to where you should make your upload request, you add a callback URL (in this case `/api/camera/blobstore-response`) to a handler that Blob Store calls when the Blob has been saved. Like this:

```
String uploadUrl = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService().createUploadUrl("/api/camera/blobstore-response");
```

So when Blob Store responds with `415 Unsupported Media Type`, that's actually the response Blob Store got from the callback handler, ie. the response that Blob Store got when calling `api/camera/blobstore`.

**The solution** is to create a handler that returns `2XX` and point Blob Store to that endpoint. This endpoint have to handle a POST request containing multipart form data.